# Maximal ideals in rings of rational fractions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So far I managed to prove this: let $k$ a field, $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $S\subset k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ the subset of polynomials without zeros on $k^n$, and for $\alpha\in k^n$, $M(\alpha)$ the maximal ideal of $S^{-1} k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ made of elements that vanish at $\alpha$ ; if $k$ is algebraically closed, or an ordered field, or a finite field, then the set of maximal ideals of $S^{-1} k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is the set of $M(\alpha)$, for all $\alpha\in k^n$.

When $k$ is algebraically closed, the nullstellensatz shows that a polynomial without zeros on $k^n$ is a non zero scalar of $k^*$. Therefore $S$ is already invertible and $S^{-1} k[X_1,\dots,X_n] = k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. The description of maximal ideals of $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ also follows from the nullstellensatz.

Now assume $k$ is an ordered field and let $J$ a maximal ideal of $S^{-1} k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. The Hilbert basis theorem shows that $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is a noetherian ring. Then the localization $S^{-1} k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is also noetherian and there exists a finite set of polynomials $P_1,\dots,P_r \in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ that generate $J$. Thus $P_1^2+\dots +P_r^2\in J$. And since $J$ has no invertible elements, there is $\alpha\in k^n$ such as $P_1^2(\alpha)+\dots +P_r^2(\alpha) = 0$. Because $k$ is an ordered field, $\alpha$ is a common zero of all $P_i$'s, and by maximality $J = M(\alpha)$.

Now assume $k$ the finite field with $q$ elements and let $J$ a maximal ideal of $S^{-1} k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. As before there exists a finite set of polynomials $P_1,\dots,P_r \in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ that generate $J$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that the $P_i$'s have no common zeros. By the nullstellensatz for finite fields, there exist polynomials $g_i$ and $g$ such as $1 = P_1 g_1+\dots+P_r g_r + g$, with $g$ vanishing on all $F_q^n$. Because $J$ is maximal, its polynomial $P_1 g_1+\dots+P_r g_r$ has a root and we get $1=0$ in $F_q^n$, which is a contradiction. Therefore there is a common zero $\alpha$ of all $P_i$'s, and by maximality $J = M(\alpha)$.

Now my question: does this hold when $k$ is any field?